# Error calling Php code from Xcode 12.2 dlopen libquic failed

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode

I recently updated to Xcode 12.2.  Now my php code (called from Xcode) to access and modify the local SQL database is broken.

Tried this solution:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_disable-library-validation

by enabling hardened runtime and then adding the runtime exception to disable library validation. Now the app crashes on startup.  The original error code (in Xcode) when trying to access the database (via php) was: `nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed`
that led me to the supposed fix above. DB is unreachable from the app.

Now I'm not sure how to proceed.  Can someone please advise.

Additionally the responseString just looks like this: `responseString = Optional(<?php (php code) ?>)` .. not running the php code at all

Another thing, I'm getting Status Code: 412 or Precondition Failed when trying to run php scripts from Xcode

Thread with similar issue:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666538

Comment: Found the solution.  You need to make sure Apache2 can run php7 code.  See here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-apache-2-not-executing-php-files/  Also you need to reconfigure php in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, search AddHandler and add 'AddHandler php7-script php' after that uncomment LoadModule with php7

Comment: 'AddHandler php7-script .php'